# Apache Calcite Fails to Parse Its Own Google BigQuery Output

Tags: google-bigquery, apache-calcite

I'm new to `Apache Calcite` and am running into a strange `"gap"` - given a simple select query:

```sql
select * from orders
```

I parse it using:

```java
SqlParser.Config sqlParserConfig = SqlParser
    .configBuilder()
    .setConformance(SqlConformanceEnum.LENIENT)
    .build();
SqlParser parser = SqlParser.create(sqlQuery, sqlParserConfig);
SqlNode parseAst = parser.parseQuery();
CalciteCatalogReader catalogReader = buildCatalogReader(schema, typeFactory);
SqlValidator.Config validatorConf = SqlValidator.Config.DEFAULT.withSqlConformance(SqlConformanceEnum.BIG_QUERY);
validatorConf = validatorConf.withIdentifierExpansion(true);
SqlValidator validator = SqlValidatorUtil.newValidator(SqlStdOperatorTable.instance(),
    catalogReader, typeFactory,
    validatorConf)
validator.validate(parseAst).toSqlString(BigQuerySqlDialect.DEFAULT).toString();
```

Which results in:

```sql
SELECT ORDERS.o_orderkey, ORDERS.o_custkey, ORDERS.o_orderstatus, ORDERS.o_totalprice, ORDERS.`o_order date`, ORDERS.o_orderpriority, ORDERS.o_clerk, ORDERS.o_shippriority, ORDERS.o_comment
FROM ORDERS AS ORDERS
(reasonable, note the quoted identifier for `o_order date`, necessary due to whitespace in columnname)
```

If I then take that query string and pass it back through `(setting conformance to  SqlConformanceEnum.BIG_QUERY)` the parse fails with:

```
org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParseException: Lexical error at line 1, column 95.  Encountered: "`" (96), after : ""
```

Puzzling on face, I tried again with a parse config:

```java
SqlParser.Config sqlParserConfig = SqlParser
    .configBuilder()
    .setConformance(getConformance(SqlConformanceEnum.BIG_QUERY))
    .setQuoting(Quoting.BACK_TICK_BACKSLASH)
    .build();
```

to force handling backtick-quoted identifiers and I up with:

```sql
SELECT ORDERS.o_orderkey AS O_ORDERKEY, ORDERS.o_custkey AS O_CUSTKEY, ORDERS.o_orderstatus AS O_ORDERSTATUS, ORDERS.o_totalprice AS O_TOTALPRICE, ORDERS.`o_order date`, ORDERS.o_orderpriority AS O_ORDERPRIORITY, ORDERS.o_clerk AS O_CLERK, ORDERS.o_shippriority AS O_SHIPPRIORITY, ORDERS.o_comment AS O_COMMENT
FROM ORDERS AS ORDERS
```

which is usable... but

1. why is the "default" conformance for BigQuery setting DOUBLE_QUOTE when bigquery uses backticks
2. why does loop-parsing lead to a different query than on the input? (running the aliased query back through a second time gets itself back, so it does stabilize, but the initial inconsistency is weird

Comment: Further addendum: given the initial failure to re-parse, I wrote a simple loop across all SqlDialect.DatabaseProduct to perform the same operation (parse select * from orders, write in a dialect-specific manner, attempt to re-parse that output, compare the initial parse output to the reparse)

Comment: Results:
14/35 dialects parsed and self-matched
20/35 dialects threw an exception while parsing (BIG_QUERY, CLICKHOUSE, MSSQL, MYSQL, DERBY, DB2, FIREBIRD, FIREBOLT, HIVE, INFORMIX, INGRES, JETHRO, INTERBASE, INFOBRIGHT, NEOVIEW, SYBASE, HSQLDB, SQLSTREAM, SPARK, UNKNOWN)
EXASOL parsed, but was not self-consistent (similar to the hand-tweaked bigquery above - the first parse is "normal", the 2nd parse aliases all columns)

Comment: Exceptions seem to fall into three categories:
Lexical error at line 1, column 8.  Encountered: "`" (96), after : ""
(for BIG_QUERY, CLICKHOUSE, SQLSTREAM, MYSQL, INFORBRIGHT, SQLSTREAM, UNKNOWN)
Encountered "[" at line 1, column 8.
(for MSSQL 
Encountered "date" at line 1, column 103.
For DERBY, DB2, FIREBIRD, FIREBOLT, HIVE, INFORMIX, INGRESS, JETHRO, INTERBASE, NEOVIEW, SYBASE, HSQLDB, SPARK)

Comment: The [ and ` errors look to be the same issue of failing to re-parse one's own identifier quoting for languages that use something other than double quotes. The other error appears to be a case of either the tokenizer spliting on the whitespace within the quoted identifier OR the "generated" SQL failing to quote `o_order date` and thus finding a fragment/reserve word "date" in the stream